# react.js rerender component only works when given another value to state, not same as before

Tags: reactjs

I want to send out a message with react in my chat application. Once the message is sent, I want the whole component to re render and then download the new message.

In my parent I created the state:

```
var [chatRoomIDs, setIDofRoom ] = React.useState(0); 

const changeChatRoomID = (id) => {
    setIDofRoom(chatRoomIDs = id); 
}
```

And then handed the necessary information to the children:

```
return (
    <div className="container">
        <div class='roomsAndMessages'>
            <ChatRegistry statePassDown={changeChatRoomID}/> 
            <ChatWindow statePassDown={chatRoomIDs} />
        </div>
        <ChatIO chatroomID={chatRoomIDs} chatRoomFunction={changeChatRoomID}/>
    </div>
)
```

Now, in chatIO I send out the message. Once the message has sent I simply do:

```
async function buttonClick() {
    await SendMessage()
    props.chatRoomFunction(0)
    props.chatRoomFunction(props.chatroomID)
}
```

So it first sends the message and then changes the value to 0, then changes it back to the original value so I get my newly sent message.

It is a workaround but it works.
It only shows the wrong chatroom (with ID 0) for one frame, so it is a minor inconvenience, seeing the screen flash.

However, this DOES work.

When I leave the `props.chatRoomFunction(0)` out, it does NO LONGER work.
I assume because the state change is fed the same exact value as it already holds. So it does nothing. While when I give it a 0 in between, the state changes twice and the new messages are loaded.

This isn't elegant - there must be a better way, right? ;-)

Comment: That is by design. If you don't change any state, the component has no reason to update. Why do you want the component to update even though nothing has changed?

Comment: because i send out a message to the server. and I thought: well to make it easy I just reload the component and therfore download my own message. So how can I force a reload then?

Comment: You can try storing the chatId as an object `{ chatId: 0 }` instead of a primitive number, that way, you can set state by doing  `props.chatRoomFunction({ chatId: props.chatroomId })`. Since a new object is always passed to the set state function, it should re-render even if props.chatroomId is the same as the existing chatId